# My Localhost is not running

Tags: asp.net

When I run my local host from VS2010, I'm getting a blank page in the browser. Which means that I'm not able to run my asp.net project.

`localhost:50319/Default.aspx`

but typing in the address bar `localhost` only display the default page.

IIS is already configured and hosted over the internet using a static IP.

Without debugging I cannot publish or make any change to my site.

Comment: Is your debugger using IIS or the VS Host?  BTW Failure to plan on your part does not constitute an emergency on my part.

Comment: I want to run locally in my machine with debugging.I am using VS2010.

Comment: Try creating new project -> ASP.net MVC4 application. Then run application. Let me know if you still see blank screen